# Impulse function and the laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I get to the following inverse Laplace transform?

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{e^{-5s} \cdot \frac 1{s+1}\right\}=u_5(t)e^{-(t-5)} \; ?$$

Here $u_5$ is a step function. I'm using my Laplace Transform table and just can't make any sense of this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does the asterisk denote convolution? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: No it does not. It denotes multiplication. Sorry for the mix up.

Comment: OK, I've changed it.  The asterisk for multiplication is a workaround for occasions when one must work only with the characters on the keyboard.  In MathJax, LaTeX, etc., one can write $2\cdot5$ or $2\times 5$, etc. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Dr.MV I thought I was able to upvote two posts to show they were both sufficient answers. However I just fixed it now since your answer was the first to help me understand my Laplace question.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I am really glad to help and pleased to hear that you are well on your way to using the Laplace Transform!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\{u(t-5)e^{-(t-5)}\}&=\int_0^{\infty} u(t-5)e^{-(t-5)}e^{-st}dt\\\\
&=\int_5^{\infty} e^{-(t-5)}e^{-st}dt\\\\
&=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t}e^{-s(t+5)}dt\\\\
&=e^{-5s}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t}e^{-st}dt\\\\
&=e^{-5s}\mathscr{L}\{e^{-t}\}\\\\
&=e^{-5s}\frac{1}{s+1}
\end{align}$$

Thus, the inverse Laplace Transform of $e^{-5s}\frac{1}{s+1}$ must be $u(t-5)e^{-(t-5)}$.

---

In general,

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\{u(t-t')f(t-t')\}&=\int_0^{\infty} u(t-t')f(t-t')e^{-st}dt\\\\
&=\int_{t'}^{\infty} f(t-t')e^{-st}dt\\\\
&=\int_0^{\infty} f(t)e^{-s(t+t')}dt\\\\
&=e^{-st'}\int_0^{\infty} f(t)e^{-st}dt\\\\
&=e^{-st'}\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}\\\\
&=e^{-st'}F(s)
\end{align}$$

and so the inverse Laplace Transform of $e^{-st'}F(s)$ must be $u(t-t')f(t-t')$.

Comment: I completely understand. Thanks you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!!  It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$ F(s)=\frac{e^{-5s}}{s} $$
and then $f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}=u(t-5)$. Then use
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s-a)\}=e^{at}f(t) $$
to get your answer.

Comment: I've seen this definition used in the book but I still am not understanding how you have come to that conclusion.

Comment: @EhBaby, note that $L^{-1}\{e^{-5s}\cdot\frac{1}{s+1}\}=e^5L^{-1}(e^{-5(s+1)}\cdot\frac{1}{s+1}\}=e^{5}L^{-1}\{F(s+1)\}$

Comment: Looked at this again today and I understand your answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: @EhBabay, I am glad it is helpful.